# MySQL: insert value into table from case expression

Tags: mysql

Below I have a procedure I run to insert some values into my shipin table. Typically I've had my Reference 2 field static, but I've since needed it to be variable. However, the field I'm pulling from, 'shipinimport'.'accountID' needs to return different results than what already exists. That's where the case expressions comes in as you can see.

My problem is, this doesn't actually insert the returned results into my shipin table. I can query it and get the results I'm looking for, but I need it to insert it into the table with the rest of the values in my procedure. I've tried moving the expression around in my procedure thinking it might be an order of events issue, but that didn't work. So is there a way to do this? Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SubjectDetailsExportToShipIn_hs`()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO ShipInImport
SELECT *
FROM dpi_timestone.SubjectDetailsView_hs;

INSERT INTO `timestone`.`shipin`
     (`REFERENCE_1`,
     `REFERENCE_2`,
     `date_loaded`,
     `location`)

SELECT
     `shipinimport`.`SubjectKey`, --Reference 1
     `shipinimport`.`AccountID`, --Reference 2
      Now(), --DateLoaded
     'DPI'--location
FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;

Select Case AccountID
      When 16 Then 191
      When 1 Then 125
    End
FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;
End
```

Comment: Your SELECT CASE is not part of an INSERT...SELECT, it is a separate query; of course it will not affect the data stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to replace those AccountID values for "Reference 2"; put the CASE in your first select, like so:

```
SELECT
     `shipinimport`.`SubjectKey`, --Reference 1
      CASE `shipinimport`.`AccountID`
        WHEN 16 THEN 191
        WHEN 1 THEN 125
        ELSE `shipinimport`.`AccountID`
      END, --Reference 2
      Now(), --DateLoaded
     'DPI'--location
FROM `dpi_timestone`.`shipinimport`;
```

If that is not the case, your code does not make it obvious where you expect 191 and 125 to end up.

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect that does seems quite obvious. I actually originally went down that path but never got rid of the select on `shipinimport`.`AccountID`, so I kept getting an error where it was returning too many columns than it was expecting.